# Up/down arrow keys suddenly jump entire webpages top/bottom?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Rather recently, and with no hardware or substantive software change, the arrow keys do not allow me to "inch" down a webpage forcing me to use the vernier control on the mouse. Windows 7, mostly Dell. Any idea of what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure caret browsing is turned off Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Untick "Always use cursor keys to navigate within pages"

Comment: my goodness! I feel so foolish and that such a simple solution works so perfectly… <Now to figure out how it got set in the first place>

Comment: you hit F7 and then clicked yes on accident.

Comment: @greenber , did this fix it ? If so, you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

For me worked just by pressing F7

Answer (score 0):

I found that option was already unticked ("Always use cursor keys to navigate within pages"); toggling it didn't fix the problem. But when I unticked "Use autoscrolling" that fixed it.